# Pybitcointools python 3.5 support

Tags: python, pybitcointools

I am trying to run [Vitalik Buterin's python bitcoin wrapper](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/blob/master/README.md).

I installed it from PyPi (`pip install pybitcointools` ).

When I try to run:

```
import bitcoin
```

I get the following error:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import bitcoin
>
> ImportError: No module named 'bitcoin'

I will appreciate any pointers on this

Comment: Do you have more than one version of python installed?

Comment: Used to have 2.7 ages ago but uninstalled it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
import pybitcointools
```

that fix my problem